# Hadoop Map Reduce Inverted Index Retrieve Line Number

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, inverted-index

I'm trying to build an inverted index search by using Hadoop Map Reduce, given as input text files, and trying to achieve the following output: word: (file#1, line#1, line#2, ….) (file#4, line#1, line#2,…) …)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of research, I've found the solution online:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-hadoop/apache-hadoop-recordreader-example/.

A custom `RecordReader` class is needed, alongside a custom `FileInputFileFormat`, in order to set the line number as the key, when the split is done by the map method. Inside the `RecordReader` implementation, custom fields can be declared and the reading of the input files can be fully managed.

In this case, adding a new `int` field called `lineNumber` for example inside the `RecordReader` custom implementation is enough, and incrementing it whenever a line is read (`nextKeyValue()` method).